# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) When Passing Dynamic Struct to Function

Tags: c, function, struct, malloc

I am trying to get this to work for my assignment but I keep getting a segmentation fault error but I can't see a problem.

```
struct line{
        int source;
        int dest;
        int type;
        int port;
        char data[51];
};


int main(){
    struct line *dataIn;
    dataIn = malloc(sizeof(struct line));
    int nRecords = 0;

    readFile(&nRecords, dataIn);

    int i=0;
    for(i = 0; 1 < 100; i++){
        printf("Source: %d Data: %s\n", dataIn[i].source, dataIn[i].data);
    }

    return 0;
}

void readFile(int *nRecords, struct line *dataIn){
    FILE *fileIn;
    fileIn =fopen("data.txt","r");
    if (!fileIn){
        puts("File Open Error");
        return 1;
    }
    while(fscanf(fileIn, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%[^\n]", &dataIn[*nRecords].source, &dataIn[*nRecords].dest, &dataIn[*nRecords].type, &dataIn[*nRecords].port, dataIn[*nRecords].data) == 5){
        nRecords++;
        dataIn = realloc(dataIn,(*nRecords+1)*sizeof(struct line));
    }
    fclose(fileIn);
}
```

Also when I add the function prototype at the top:

```
void readFile(int*, struct line*);
```

I get the error:

> Conflicting Types for 'readFile'

Comment: You're updating `nRecords` but not using that in the for loop. Why?

Comment: Your function readFile return -1 if fileIn is null but is of type void. Also make sure that  the function prototype is after the struct declaration.

Comment: Why `char data[51]` for data?  You said you where parsing a "dynamic structure".  If your input is > 51 bytes, you will scribble over the stack pointer and be unable to return from `readFile()`.  I think you need to do two things.  1. rethink the way you manage memory as this is quite convoluted and will be hard to support.  2. Stop using any form of scanf as it's dangerous.

Comment: Don't forget to free what you malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C uses pass-by-value for function parameter passing. In your code, `dataIn` itself is passed to `readFile()` using pass-by-value.

Now,  `dataIn` being a pointer itself, you can change the content of `dataIn` from the function, but you cannot change `dataIn` itself (look at the `realloc()`) from the function, and expect that to get reflected back to `main()`.

So, after returning, your `dataIn` has just one element, as it was `malloc()`ed previously. Then, the for loop obviously try to access out of bound memory, creating [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to change `dataIn` from the function, you need to pass a pointer to it to the function.

That said,

- `nRecords` being a pointer, `nRecords++;` will **not** update the corresponding `int` value.
- The `void` function `readFile()` should not have a `return` statement with a value like `return 1;`

Comment: Also, you update `nRecords`, which is a pointer. You should write `*nRecords++`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks, added the same. :)